# Weird black boxes appearing on windows 14.4

Tags: unity, compiz

This is probably one of the weirdest problems I have ever had in all my years of using linux. I recently installed Ubuntu into a chroot on my Chromebook, and installed a lot of software. Today, after rebooting and re-entering unity, I see weird black bars around menu items, and over top of almost all windows. I've tried everything I can think of. I've reset unity and compiz multiple times, reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and unity, but nothing has worked. I can't even take a screenshot of the problems because the screenshot window is also just a black box. I still have access to the command line. Please help.

EDIT: I was able to take a picture with my phone and upload it.
[Black boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v14A.jpg)

Comment: Can you take a photo with your phone and post the image?

Comment: yes. Post is updated.

Comment: Exact thing has just happened after a big upgrade and reboot, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment I had this issue (U 15.10) after installing an update involving some intel graphics. Using TTY1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1) -- as the GUI terminal was unusable -- running `apt-get dist-upgrade` upgraded some other parts of the intel graphics (didn't take note of what). After that and a reboot all was well.